# Android LibGdx живые обои

Tags: android, libgdx, livewallpaper

Я разрабатываю приложение для установки живых обоев на LibGDX

У меня есть класс, который рисует то, что можно поставить на обои. Этот класс не является живыми обоями, я добавляю его на обычную активити в качестве фрагмента:

```
class MyGdxGame : ApplicationAdapter() {

  private lateinit var stars: Stars
  private lateinit var bg: GameBackground
  private lateinit var presentation: Presentation
  private var prevTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()

  private lateinit var sr: ShapeRenderer
  private lateinit var sb: SpriteBatch

  override fun create() {
    super.create()
    sr = ShapeRenderer().apply { setAutoShapeType(true) }
    sb = SpriteBatch()

    bg = GameBackground(sr)
    stars = Stars(sr)
    presentation = Presentation(sr, sb)
  }

  override fun render() {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val elapsedTime = now - prevTime
    if (elapsedTime > FRAME_DURATION) {
      prevTime = now
      bg.frame(FRAME_DURATION)
      stars.frame(FRAME_DURATION)
      presentation.frame(FRAME_DURATION)
    }

    bg.draw()
    stars.draw()
    presentation.draw()
  }

  override fun dispose() {
    sr.dispose()
    sb.dispose()
  }

  companion object {
    private const val FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60
    private const val FRAME_DURATION = DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS / FRAMES_PER_SECOND
  }
}
```

Сколько бы раз я не запускал приложение, этот класс всегда все отрисовывает правильно, так как я и задумывал.

Но есть еще один класс, который рисует все то же самое, но он является живыми обоями, так он выглядит:

```
class LiveWallpaperScreen : ApplicationListener, AndroidWallpaperListener {

  private var prev = 0L

  private lateinit var stars: Stars
  private lateinit var bg: GameBackground
  private lateinit var presentation: Presentation

  private lateinit var sr: ShapeRenderer
  private lateinit var sb: SpriteBatch

  override fun render() {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val delta = time - prev
    if (delta > FRAME_DURATION) {
      frame(delta)
      draw()
      prev = time
    }
  }

  override fun create() {
    sr = ShapeRenderer().apply { setAutoShapeType(true) }
    sb = SpriteBatch()
    bg = GameBackground(sr)
    stars = Stars(sr)
    presentation = Presentation(sr, sb)
  }

  private fun frame(timeElapsed: Long) {
    bg.frame(timeElapsed)
    stars.frame(timeElapsed)
    presentation.frame(timeElapsed)
  }

  private fun draw() {
    bg.draw()
    stars.draw()
    presentation.draw()
  }

  override fun pause() {
  }

  override fun resume() {
  }

  override fun dispose() {
    sr.dispose()
    sb.dispose()
  }

  override fun resize(width: Int, height: Int) {
    Log.d("lol", "resize $width---$height")
  }

  override fun previewStateChange(isPreview: Boolean) {
    Log.d("lol", "previewStateChange isPreview=$isPreview")
  }

  override fun iconDropped(x: Int, y: Int) {
    Log.d("lol", "iconDropped x=$x---y=$y")

  }

  override fun offsetChange(xOffset: Float, yOffset: Float, xOffsetStep: Float, yOffsetStep: Float, xPixelOffset: Int, yPixelOffset: Int) {
    Log.d("lol", "offsetChange xOffset=$xOffset yOffset=$yOffset xOffsetStep=$xOffsetStep yOffsetStep=$yOffsetStep xPixelOffset=$xPixelOffset yPixelOffset=$yPixelOffset")
    val steps = (1.0f / xOffsetStep).roundToInt() + 1

  }

  companion object {
    private const val FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60
    private const val FRAME_DURATION = DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS / FRAMES_PER_SECOND
  }
}
```

Проблема вот в чем: если несколько раз переключиться между активити, на которой рисует первый класс, и экраном для установки живых обоев, на которой работает второй класс, то будут возникать вот такие забавные артефакты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы могли понять, изображение справа - неправильное. Я могу наблюдать его как на системном экране превью обоев, так и собственно на обоях.

Известно что два этих класса никогда не отрисовываются одновременно, также у каждого из них свои `SpriteBatch` и `ShapeRenderer`.

Понимаю, что кода, которого я приложил, скорее всего, мало. Но реально не знаю какая часть кода может породить такой ужас, поэтому я надеюсь, что кто-то из вас просто во время разработки на LibGDX столкнулся с подобным. Пишите любые возможные варианты.

UPDATE

Вот еще картинка, которая поможет понять, что именно не так. На этой кратинке вы видите 4 фигуры. Верхний белый круг отрисован `ShapreRenderer`'ом, остальные три - текстуры, отрисованные `SpriteBatch`'ем. Как видно, текстуры просто поменялись, сохраняя свои размеры?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно смотреть код который рисует и код который отвечает за подгрузку спрайтов. И не совсем понятно зачем делать объект составным, может проще один цельный спрайт использовать?..